# How Does This Palindrome Function Work?

Tags: java

I was give the following snippet of code to help me with a problem that involves the palindrome of a number. I am at a loss to figure out how this works exactly. I understand that it involves the while loop but am unable to follow the logic.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int nr) {
            int rev = 0;
            int x = nr;

            while (x > 0) {
                rev = 10 * rev + x % 10;
                x /= 10;
            }
       return rev == nr;
    }
```

Can someone please explain how this works?

Comment: Write it down on paper for a small number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A palindrome is a number which reads same whether you read it from left to right or from right to left.
For Example - 1221

Now the execution

Suppose you have entered 1221 as the number.
Your calling method statement will look like 
isPalindrome(1221);

**Step 1** - Here we have three variables nr = 1221 , rev = 0 and x which will hold the original value which is 1221.

As soon as while loop begins it checks whether x is greater than zero or not, in our case 1221 is greater than 0 which is true so the program will go inside the loop.

Then     rev = 10 * rev + x % 10;

This expression will change the initial value of rev which is zero.

10* 0 + 1221 % 10 will give 1 as the answer. since % modulus operator gives the remainder so 1221 when divided by 10 will give 1 as the remainder.

Now rev has 1 as its value.

Program will go to next statement to update the value of x as we have already stored one digit of our palindrome entry.

```
x / = 10 ;
```

This is a shorthand statement which is equivalent to 
    x = x / 10;
So here when x is divided by 10 we will get 122 as the quotient and 122 will be stored in x.

**Step 2** - Now program flow will agin go to the first statement, ( thats the beauty of loops) to check for the condition whicha gain willl be true as x = 122 is greater than 0.
 and now the value of rev will be

```
rev = 10 * 1 ( remember value of rev is 1 at the moment) +       122% 10 ;
```

the new value of rev will be
    rev = 10 * 1 + 2 ( since modulus or remainder of 122 when divided by 10 is 2 )

final value according to first statement would be 
    rev = 12.

and program will be ahead to change the value of x since we are done with last two digit of our entered number.

```
x = x / 10; which will result us the quotient of 12.
```

**Step 3** - 12 is greater than 0 condition true program will move to next statement.

```
rev = 10 * rev (12) + x (12) % 10;
```

new rev value 
    rev = 120 + 2 ;
    rev = 122

the next statement will give us another changed value of x so that we can complete our palindrome digit.

```
x = x / 10;
x = 12/10; will give us 1 as quotient
```

**Step 4** - while condition will again be satisfied which is 1 is greater than 0

and the updated rev value would be

```
rev = 10* rev (122) + 1% 10;
```

since diving 1 with ten will give us the remainder 1 , so the final expression will be 
    rev = 1221

and now the last change is value of x
    x = x(1) \ 10 ;
x will be zero as there will be no quotient when dividing 1 with ten.

**Step 5**- 0 is greater than 0 condition will be false and program will exit the while and the final values of all the variables will be

```
nr = 1221
rev = 1221
x = 0
```

few statements inside your method will justify the return type Boolean.

```
if(nr==rev)
  return true ;
else 
  return false;
```

I hope I could explain you the flow, also would like you to dry run the same program for non palindrome digit.

Answer (score 6):

If the number is a palindrome, then `rev` will equal the number after the loop finishes. Here's how it works, with a sample iteration where `nr` is 121:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int nr) {
        int rev = 0;
        int x = nr; // 121

        while (x > 0) {
            rev = 10 * rev + x % 10; // x % 10 is the last digit of x when in base 10. multiplying the previous value of rev by 10 and adding x % 10 is adding the last digit of x to the next digit of rev
// step 1: rev = 10*0 + 1 = 1
// step 2: rev = 10*1 + 2 = 12
// step 3: rev = 10*12 + 1 = 121
            x /= 10; // truncates the last digit of x
        }
```

so the return statement should be `return rev == nr;`

Comment: Adding a sample iteration would make your answer way better, say with `nr=22` and explaining step by step within the iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- added.

Answer (score 1):

Original fragment of code when input parameter nr (later x, x>0) makes two things:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int nr) {
    int rev = 0;
    int x = nr;

    while (x > 0) {
        rev = 10 * rev + x % 10; // impl., for examp. 13 / 10 = 1
        x /= 10;  // f truncation of x
    }
```

Comment: Thanks now I see what is going on!

Comment: `x /= 10` can be done on an int without an error being thrown -- it'll just truncate the last digit off of x in base 10. basically it's the floor function of x/10

Comment: agree with @Santiago Benoit here 
x there is purposly int there.
No error would be thrown.
x will simpmy return you the int value after the division which would be your qoutient.